# GWT + EJB 3.0 + Eclipse + Java EE + Weblogic 10g

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I'm pretty new with EJB's and GWT but I've been using Java for a little while.

My question is: How do I get GWT and EJB's running all together on eclipse? I keep getting pretty severe memory issues with it all together. It consumes 600mb of VM and 200mb of mem and every other operation I do (i.e. open a .java file or build), it crashes with a permgen error. I have installed eclipse helios with java ee, and installed gwt as a plugin. I then installed the Oracle Weblogic eclipse plugin. Is there a better setup or IDE?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using MyEclipse and it allows me to use EJB + GWT + Java EE + Weblogic stably. It comes with its own plugins for Weblogic and has wizards for creating EJBs. You can install the GWT plugin through its dashboard as well.

Another solution is to forget Weblogic altogether and use a different server such as JBoss or Tomcat. This isn't really a solution as it is a compromise. JBoss and Tomcat seem to work well with Eclipse Helio Java EE and even with GWT.

**Setups that are usable:**

```
- Eclipse Helio Java EE + JBoss + GWT (compromise)
- Eclipse Helio Java EE + Tomcat + GWT (compromise)
- MyEclipse + GWT (real solution)
```

Hopefully this helps someone who's starting out with EJBs like me.

Answer (score 1):

When you get permgen errors, the solution is usually to edit your `eclipse.ini`. Look for the line

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=...m
```

and increase the value. The permgen space is separate from the heap and stack space, so increasing them doesn't help. It's also pretty usual, that the default MaxPermSize value in the eclipse.ini is too small.

Comment: How much can I increase it by? I've currently it set to 1024m right now.

Comment: @Kenneth: 1024 megabytes is very, very much (I wouldn't set it that high). If it doesn't work with that, and if you're sure, that it doesn't get set anywhere else (attention: some eclipse.inis erroneously contain two `-XX:MaxPermSize` lines), then there has to be a more severe problem with the plugins.

Comment: I have tried Oracle Workshop 10g (Oracle's version of eclipse with their own weblogic plugin). I found that it also crashes quite a bit when creating an EJB project. I think you are right; perhaps Oracle's official weblogic plugin eats up all the memory.